# Expected number of random real numbers from $0$ to $1$ needed for their sum to exceed $n$: Why does it approach $2n+\frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, expected-value

Let $E_n=$ expected number of uniformly random real numbers from $0$ to $1$ needed for their sum to exceed $n$.

Using the probability density function of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), I worked out that:

$$E_n=\sum_{i=n}^\infty{\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}{\frac{(-1)^ji(i-n)(n-j)^{i-1}}{j!(i-j)!}}\right)}$$

which has a [closed form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformSumDistribution.html) in terms of $e$:

$$E_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(k-n)^k}{k!}e^{n-k}}$$

So we have:

$E_1=e=2.71828...$
$E_2=e^2-e=4.67077...$
$E_3=e^3-2e^2+\frac{1}{2}e=6.66657...$
$E_4=e^4-3e^3+2e^2-\frac{1}{6}e=8.666604...$
$E_5=e^5-4e^4+\frac{9}{2}e^3-\frac{4}{3}e^2+\frac{1}{24}e=10.6666621...$
$E_6=e^6-5e^5+8e^4-\frac{9}{2}e^3+\frac{2}{3}e^2-\frac{1}{120}e=12.6666671...$
etc.

It is evident that $E_n\to2n+\frac{2}{3}$ as $n\to\infty$. My question is, how can we prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(E_n-2n)=\frac{2}{3}$$

(Context: I was trying to generalize [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u).)

EDIT: I just found that this is essentially a duplicate of [this answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636576/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-sum-limits-k-0n-left-frac-left?rq=1). The link appeared in the "Related" question list on the right side.

Comment: See the answer by user jmerry at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068112/what-is-the-expected-number-of-randomly-generated-numbers-in-the-range-a-b-re/3069409#3069409 (the one starting with "All right, now that rigorous argument I alluded to.")